# How to reverse the order of sets of characters in a string using flip?

Tags: kdb

I want to reverse the order of currencies for each element in the list, i.e. CADUSD needs to become USDCAD.

```
ccys:("CADUSD";"NZDUSD"; "USDAUD")
"" sv/:flip(-3,3)#'\:ccys
```

The above does this. I have read that flip x returns x transposed and # is the take operator; but I am not able to understand clearly how ' and flip(-3,3)# achieve this.

Could you please help me understand this?
Alternatively, is there a simpler way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ccys and (-3 3) are different lengths, you need the each left and each both to apply 3 and -3 with `#` to each string in ccys rather than ccys itself.

```
// each left will apply -3 & 3 # to the entire ccys list
q)-3 3#\:ccys
"CADUSD" "NZDUSD" "USDAUD"
"CADUSD" "NZDUSD" "USDAUD"

// each both will then apply the -3 & 3 # to each nested string
q)(-3,3)#'\:ccys
"USD" "USD" "AUD"
"CAD" "NZD" "USD"

// flip then transposes the 2 by 3 matrix of strings 
// to a 3 by 2 matrix of strings
q)flip (-3,3)#'\:ccys
"USD" "CAD"
"USD" "NZD"
"AUD" "USD"

// this each right sv (scalar from vector) will merge each  
// ccy into a currency pair. sv basically combines a list of strings,
// seperated by the left argument which in this case is nothing / ""
"" sv/:

// I would more commonly use raze each for this part:
q)raze each flip -3 3#'\:ccys
"USDCAD"
"USDNZD"
"AUDUSD"
```

As for a simpler approach, since the strings are all the same length and you just want to swap the first and last 3 characters around, you could index at depth to achieve this:

```
q)ccys[;3 4 5 0 1 2]
"USDCAD"
"USDNZD"
"AUDUSD"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `rotate` keyword can also achieve this if you know all currencies are 3-char:

```
q)3 rotate/:ccys
"USDCAD"
"USDNZD"
"AUDUSD"
```

Comment: Or very slightly simpler `3 rotate'ccys`.